# Textarea auto-complete angularjs only 10 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Why have i only 10 items in autocomplete ?
I have in cake view code:

```
<?php $leadersOptions = array(
            array('id' => '1', 'text' => '1'),
            array('id' => '2', 'text' => '2'),
            array('id' => '3', 'text' => '3'),
            array('id' => '4', 'text' => '4'),
            array('id' => '5', 'text' => '5'),
            array('id' => '6', 'text' => '6'),
            array('id' => '7', 'text' => '7'),
            array('id' => '8', 'text' => '8'),
            array('id' => '9', 'text' => '9'),
            array('id' => '10', 'text' => '10'),
            array('id' => '11', 'text' => '11'),
            array('id' => '12', 'text' => '12')
); ?>
<?php $encoded = json_encode($leadersOptions); ?>

<div ng-controller="TagsCtrl">
    <textarea ng-init="leadersOptions = <?php echo empty($leadersOptions) ? '[]' :h($encoded); ?>; leaders = <?php echo empty($projectUser) ? '[]' :h(json_encode($projectUser)); ?>" class="ng-hide" name="data[Project][leader_id]">
        {{leaders}}
    </textarea>

    <label>Dodaj leadera</label>
    <tags-input ng-model="leaders" placeholder="Kliknij aby wybrać" add-on-paste="true" add-on-enter="false" add-on-space="false" add-on-comma="false" add-on-blur="false">
        <auto-complete source="loadTags()" load-on-focus="true" load-on-down-arrow="true" load-on-empty="true">
        </auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
</div>
```

And in angular ctr:

```
app.controller('TagsCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $sce, $http, $rootScope) {

    $scope.loadTags = function (query, tags) {
        return $scope.leadersOptions;
    }
    $scope.loadContractors = function (query, tags) {
        return $scope.contractorsOptions;
    }
    $scope.loadUserCategory = function () {
        return $scope.categoriesOptions;
    }
});
```

And still it suggest 10 elements but in $leadersOptions is 12 element and more...

[Elements in suggest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI8cg.jpg)
 And array with elements ($leadersOptions):

```
<?php $leadersOptions = array (
    array('id' => '1', 'text' => '1'),
    array('id' => '2', 'text' => '2'),
    array('id' => '3', 'text' => '3'),
    array('id' => '4', 'text' => '4'),
    array('id' => '5', 'text' => '5'),
    array('id' => '6', 'text' => '6'),
    array('id' => '7', 'text' => '7'),
    array('id' => '8', 'text' => '8'),
    array('id' => '9', 'text' => '9'),
    array('id' => '10', 'text' => '10'),
    array('id' => '11', 'text' => '11'),
    array('id' => '12', 'text' => '12')
);?>
```

Can anyone help me ? I am not good at angularJS... Thanks.

Comment: what is h($encoded) function code look like?

Comment: Try to make your code into an [mcve], if at all possible isolating the issue to *either* a back-end *or* a front-end issue.

Comment: @mtamma - Convenience method for htmlspecialchars. This method do nothing in this case... :(

Comment: @Jeroen - I corrected code and category of topic

Comment: Is in angular default parameter which sets number of records to display in auto-complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. In auto-complete i added 'max-results-to-show="99"'.

Now code looks like this:

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags()" load-on-focus="true" max-results-to-show="99" load-on-down-arrow="true" load-on-empty="true"></auto-complete>
```